# how to get unspents of an address using bitcoind?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, listunspent

I am using bitcoind. I have gone through the json-rpc api's.

```
listunspent [minconf=1] [maxconf=999999]    version 0.7 Returns array of unspent transaction inputs in the wallet.
```

listunspent method gives an unspent transaction inputs of the addresses in the wallet.

I want to get an unspent transaction inputs of one particular bitcoin address which are currently not part of our wallet. Could anyone tell me how to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send your addresses as following:

```
bitcoin-cli listunspent 0 9999999 '["1PGFqEzfmQch1gKD3ra4k18PNj3tTUUSqg","1LtvqCaApEdUGFkpKMM4MstjcaL4dKg8SP"]'
```